# ANTLR 4 Parsing Problems: Works with TestRig But Not in Java

Tags: java, antlr4

I'm writing a lambda calculus interpreter in Java using ANTLR 4.8.  Parsing works as expected when using the TestRun tool.  However, inside my Java code, I end up with empty parsing lists whenever I parse lambda expressions with the `abstractionExpr` rule in them.  I don't understand the discrepancy between TestRun and my Java code.

Here is an example using TestRun:

```
$ grun LambdaExpr lexpr -tree
^x.y
(lexpr ^ x . (lexpr y))
```

And here is the output of my Java program when parsing the same expression:

```
$ java LambdaCalculusInterpreter
Parse tree output: []
```

Below is my grammar:

```
grammar LambdaExpr;

Var         : [a-z]+ ;

WS          : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;


lexpr       : Var                   # varExpr
            | '^' Var '.' lexpr     # abstractionExpr
            | '(' lexpr lexpr ')'   # applicationExpr
            ;
```

Below is my Java code:

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;

public class LambdaCalculusInterpreter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    CharStream inputStream = CharStreams.fromString("^x.y");
    LambdaExprLexer lexer = new LambdaExprLexer(inputStream);
    CommonTokenStream commonTokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    LambdaExprParser parser = new LambdaExprParser(commonTokenStream);

    ParseTree tree = parser.lexpr();
    System.out.println("Parse tree output: " + tree.toString());
}
```

Comment: Quick sanity check: have you done a clean build to make sure all the classes generated by Antlr have been regenerated?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still running into this problem even after removing all files generated by ANTLR.

Comment: Debug your lexpr() call to see why it doesn't produce a parse tree. What's also interesting to check is if parse tree generation is even enabled. I thought it would be by default, but better double check it/activate it explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `toString` is inherited from `org.antlr.v4.runtime.RuleContext`, which has a different implementation than you expect. You'll want to call `toStringTree(...)`:

```java
ParseTree tree = parser.lexpr();
System.out.println("Parse tree output: " + tree.toStringTree(parser));
```

which prints:

```
Parse tree output: (lexpr ^ x . (lexpr y))
```

Also make sure you're using `org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree`, not some other `ParseTree` class that happens to be present in your classpath (which might not be the case).